# How can I go to the definition (gD) in a new tab?

Tags: neovim, lsp

I am using Typescript and I have this config for going to the definition when hovering over a function name:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', 'gD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, bufopts) -- does not work
vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts) -- works
```

When I enter `gD`, it returns the following error:

```
method textDocument/declaration is not supported by any of the servers registered for the current buffer
```

I'd like to open the file containing the function definition in a new tab. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't have the distinction declaration and definition in typescript like you have it in C or C++.

`myfile.h`

```c
// declaration
int myfunction(int a, char *name);
```

`myfile.c`

```c
// definition
int myfunction(int a, char *name)
{
  return a * a;
}
```

In typescript you have only a definition that that is probably why `gD` is not working but `gd` should do the job for you.

To open the definition in a new tab if it is another file you could do:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts)

vim.keymap.set('n', 'gD', function()
        local org_path = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)

        -- Go to definition:
        vim.api.nvim_command('normal gd')

        -- Wait LSP server response
        vim.wait(100, function() end)

        local new_path = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)
        if not (org_path == new_path) then
            -- Create a new tab for the original file
            vim.api.nvim_command('0tabnew %')

            -- Restore the cursor position
            vim.api.nvim_command('b ' .. org_path)
            vim.api.nvim_command('normal! `"')

            -- Switch to the original tab
            vim.api.nvim_command('normal! gt')
        end
    end, bufopts)
```

Comment: ooo that makes sense. Is there a way to make `gd` open a new file? I can just map `gD` to that

Comment: `gd` should open a new file if the definition is in another file.

Comment: Oh I meant in a new tab instead of replacing the current one

Comment: Do you really mean a new tab spreading the entire GUI or a new buffer available via 'tab' provide by a bufferline plugin?

Comment: New tab within vim, like what `:tabe [filename]` does

Comment: I'll try to do that for you tomorrow ;-)

Comment: egad, what a hack! :P

Comment: this worked!! had to add `local` in front of org_path and new_path

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have adapted the solution with your suggestion :-)